# How to enable navigator.hardwareConcurrency in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser, webbrowser-control

For my model I need to enable navigator.hardwareConcurrency for Safari browser so that I can get to see how many virtual core a client has.

I found following statement on canIuse.com, but still do not know how to enable, and it's kind of vague to me how to enable this.

`WebKit browsers clamp the maximum value returned to 2 on iOS devices and 8 on all others. Disabled in Safari behind the ENABLE_NAVIGATOR_HWCONCURRENCY build option.`

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer.   I believe you need to enable that in the browser code at compile time.  So unless you're compiling the browser it cannot be done.   The following site https://caniuse.com/#feat=hardwareconcurrency says that it will return a 2 on iOS and 8 on others when it is enabled.  So you could wrap your call to get the hardware concurency and handle Safari specially returning either 2 or 8 for Safari depending on the os.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289465/get-number-of-cpu-cores-in-javascript) for more.