# webassembly and get_nprocs()

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, emscripten, webassembly

Consider the following example (from get_nprocs man page):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("This system has %d processors configured and "
            "%d processors available.\n",
            get_nprocs_conf(), get_nprocs());
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It compiles&runs using g++. However when compiling with emscripten em++ I get the following error:

```
em++ nproc.cpp -o nproc.html
error: undefined symbol: get_nprocs
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0`
error: undefined symbol: get_nprocs_conf
Error: Aborting compilation due to previous errors
shared:ERROR: '/home/hiisi/workspace/emsdk/node/8.9.1_64bit/bin/node /home/hiisi/workspace/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten/src/compiler.js /tmp/tmp2SSe0B.txt /home/hiisi/workspace/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten/src/library_pthread_stub.js' failed (1)
```

How do I use `get_nprocs()` with webassembly?

Comment: @freakish thank you so much! Would you please answer the question rather than commenting on it? So that I could choose your answer and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that sysinfo is still not implemented: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/8038 The number of cores can be retrieved from JS though: [Get number of CPU cores in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289465/get-number-of-cpu-cores-in-javascript)